# Wrong sequence of events in Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor server-side application. In the code-behind in .razor.cs of a component I have

```
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        ...

        _role = await Authorization.GetCurrentUserRoleAsync();
        QuoteModel = await QuotesDb.GetQuoteByIdAsync(_role, QuoteId);
```

In the .razor:

```
@if((DateTime.Now - QuoteModel.Date).TotalDays > 60)
{
    ... do something
}
```

When the application is run,

```
_role = await Authorization.GetCurrentUserRoleAsync();
```

in the code-behind is executed, and then in razor

```
@if((DateTime.Now - QuoteModel.Date).TotalDays > 60)
```

is executed, before QuoteModel is instantiated in code-behind, which of course causes a null reference exception.

How can I make sure QuoteModel is instantiated before it is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle that with a null check:

```
@if(QuoteModel != null && DateTime.Now - QuoteModel.Date).TotalDays > 60)
```